# For loop in VBA misbehaving, and not running the way I would like

Tags: excel, vba

What I am doing here is converting strings stored as text to an integer. Unfortunately just changing the format from general to numeric doesn't do the trick, and what the guy before me did was manually find/replace each individual digit (i.e. use the excel find replace for 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.)

The problem that I'm having with the code below is that it will only replace some of the digits, but not all. I can't even figure out a set pattern in which it does it. As far as I can tell the for statement should run it for each each "Digit" value from 0 to 9 right? So why doesn't it replace all of the strings?

```
Dim Digit As Integer
Dim ReplacementRange As Range

Set ReplacementRange = Range("Table1[AR]")`

Digit = 0


For Digit = 0 To Digit = 9

    ReplacementRange.Replace What:=Digit, Replacement:=Digit, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False         
    Digit = Digit + 1

Next
```

Comment: You're converting numbers stored as text to numbers? Why not just run `ReplacementRange.value = ReplacementRange.value`.

Comment: Tried using worksheet value function on numeric text string and copying value back to cell?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot... Thanks for that. I'm going to go pound my head into a wall for a bit. You just made my day though. Thanks!

Comment: Put my comment as an answer then, I don't like unanswered questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quickly convert numbers stored as text within a range to their numeric values, you can simply place the values into the range like so:

`ReplacementRange.value = ReplacementRange.value`

---

EDIT: I had time, so I thought I'd add what is wrong with what you were doing beside it being a complicated alternative to a simple solution:

The for loop is structured wrong. The correct minimal syntax is `[variable] = [startValue] to [endValue]` for example: `For x = 0 to 1`.

`For Digit = 0 To Digit = 9` ends up being evaluated equivalent to `For Digit = 0 to 0` (because you previously set Digit to 0. This means the loop only ever runs for a value of `Digit = 0`. You're also incrementing Digit within the loop, which is more reasonably handled by increasing the step. In this case, you want to hit every digit so you shouldn't increment the value.

To fix your loop, you would need to do the following:

```
For Digit = 0 To 9
    ReplacementRange.Replace What:=Digit, Replacement:=Digit, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False         
Next
```

But... that still won't solve the issue of numbers stored as text.

Comment: Worked brilliantly, and I felt like a complete idiot. To explain why I did it they way I was trying- automating the way the guy before me did it instead of thinking. Much obliged Daniel!

Comment: In case you don't know, you accept Daniel's answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, turning it a pleasant shade of green.

Comment: I did not know that- I have fixed that. Thanks Doug!